# jquery .hover - 1st argument not working

Tags: jquery, hover

I'm attempting to use .hover on a drop down menu.

I have it set up so the menu title shows the current page, but when you hover over the menu, the menu title changes to the homepage name. kinda like this: http://juerglehni.com/works/empty-words

this is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#nav" ).hover(
    function(){
        $("#dynamictitle").html("<a href="/">homepage</a>");
        },
    function(){
        $("#dynamictitle").html("current page");
        }
    );

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6gbRe/7/

The first hover argument changes the menu title to nothing when the mouse enters, but the second argument works when the mouse leaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes in the string your are trying to set as the HTML like this:

```
$("#dynamictitle").html("<a href=\"/\">homepage</a>");
```

Or instead use single quotes like this:

```
$("#dynamictitle").html("<a href='/'>homepage</a>");
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle with escaped double quotes](http://jsfiddle.net/6gbRe/8/) and another  [with single quotes](http://jsfiddle.net/6gbRe/9/).

Comment: Ah! simple mistake. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the quotes:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#nav" ).hover(
    function(){
        $("#dynamictitle").html("<a href=\"/\">homepage</a>");
        },
    function(){
        $("#dynamictitle").html("current page");
        }
    );

});
```